# Is a PHP session variable shared across running scripts?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, shared

Are session variables in the global $_SESSION array shared across scripts? Lets say I place a value into $_SESSION['box'], can another simultaneously running script store *another value* with the same key? Will they conflict? Or will it manage the actual variable values based upon the session ID from the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the same browser call 2 pages that set the same session variable, whichever one gets processed last will set the value.

If you have 2 separate browsers/users accessing the same 2 pages, they will set unique values.

Answer (score 2):

Data stored in session is stored on a per-client basis -- the ID being generally passed by a cookie.

This means you cannot have two users accessing the same session ; it's not what it exists for.

=> 2 users / browsers / clients = 2 different sessions = 2 different values.

If you are asking about two scripts requested by the same use/client, and using file-based sessions (which is the default), the session-file of that user should be locked by the first script that begun, so two scripts don't access it at the same time -- which might cause problems if two scripts are trying to modify the session simultaneously.

=> 1 user, with 2 requests = one will be executed ; then, only, the second one will be executed ; means data set by the first one will be visible from the second one -- which will be executed only after the first one is finished.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then the answer is the latter: Session variables are managed according to the session ID *which is allocated to* the client.

A 'session' refers to a user/browser-session. New user/browser, new session, new variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's unique per user session, but available globally within that user's session.  If one script sets a variable with that key, and the second script being executed by the same user sets a variable with the same key, it is overwritten for just that user.